# How to get other model which belongsTo current model via join table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

There are 3 tables (models): **Booking, User, Hotel**.

Booking `belongsTo` both User and Hotel.

User `hasMany` Booking, and Hotel `hasMany` Booking, too.

How to get all Hotels, which User has Booking for them? As any array (collection) which is iterateable.

Answer (score 2):

user model

```
public function hotels(){
  // where booking is the name of the pivot table
  return $this -> belongsToMany('Hotel','booking') 
         ->pivot('columns from pivot table'); <-- optional: only if you want to return columns from the pivot table.

}
```

hotel model

```
public function users(){
   // where booking is the name of the pivot table
  return $this -> belongsToMany('User','booking') 
         ->pivot('columns from pivot table'); <-- optional: only if you want to return columns from the pivot table.
}

$hotels = User::with('hotels') -> get(); 
$users = Hotel::with('users') -> get();
```

Et voila, you have all the hotels where the user has made a booking.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hotels.booking_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `hotels`.*, `bookings`.`user_id` from `hotels` inner join `bookings` on `bookings`.`id` = `hotels`.`booking_id` where `bookings`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3)

Comment: In the hasManyThrough example in docs, it says that post is related to user, and user related to country. So it's possible to use `user` as a bridge. But in my case, booking related to both hotel and user. and hotel is linked with `hasMany` to booking.

Comment: @kikio my bad, you need pivot table instead,  I have updated my code, let me know. sorry for the mix up.

Comment: No problem, but whats `column in booking`?

Comment: @kikio, if you want to get data from booking, just add the column name to the relation.